# Reduce number of operations to get one array value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't wrap my head around that. There seem to be a lot of redundancy, and even if it is not called called more than ten times in the main loop, I still find it hard to swallow that it loops through the whole list at each invocation.

```
def get_file_info(f, stream, field):

    discoverer = GstPbutils.Discoverer()
    discoverer.connect('discovered', on_discovered)
    info = discoverer.discover_uri(f)

    for vinfo in info.get_video_streams():
        ftype = (vinfo.get_stream_type_nick())
        width = vinfo.get_width()
        height = (format(vinfo.get_height()))
        depth = (format(vinfo.get_depth()))
        framerate = ('Frate: {}'.format(vinfo.get_framerate_num()))
        bitrate = ('Brate: {}'.format(vinfo.get_max_bitrate()))
        par = vinfo.get_par_num()
        fname = vinfo.get_caps().to_string().split(',')[0]

    if stream == 'video':
        if field == 'duration':
            return str(convert_time(info.get_duration(), 'hh:mm:ss'))
        elif field == 'width':
            return str(width)
        elif field == 'height':
            return str(height)
        elif field == 'type':
            return str(ftype)
        elif field == 'depth':
            return str(depth)
        elif field == 'framerate':
            return str(framerate)
        elif field == 'bitrate':
            return str(bitrate)
        elif field == 'par':
            return str(par)
        elif field == 'name':
            return str(par)
```

I read [the lambda documentation](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk), but can't seem to write a proper one, but I would sure like to.

Comment: Are the fields either "duration", or "width" or .... "name", or can it contain any string?

Comment: Yes! they are just a fixed set of no more than the nine listed here ; No, it can **not** contain any string.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

@Stewie Griffin's answer is good, but I dare say it promotes `eval`, where `dict` is safer and more expansive.
The main aim here is to use the same if's as Stewie, as they are definitely good.
As a dictionary contains things and you can't get other things out of it it's safer.
With Stiewies for example you can pass `'get_file_info'` as the `field` and it'll give you `'<function get_file_info at 0x03335150>'`.
It also means that you can return a dictionary for each and every stream in `info.get_video_streams()`.

To obtain this we will make a variable `video_info` that will hold the needed information.

```
video_info = {
    'width': 2,
    'height': 3,
    'name': 'Name of video'
}

field = 'width'
str(video_info[field])
Out[3]: '2'

field = 'name'
str(video_info[field])
Out[5]: 'Name of video'
```

This means we just need to move all the information into this dictionary.
And so you'll need to change the for-loop to create a dictionary.

```
video_info = {
    'type': vinfo.get_stream_type_nick(),
    'width': vinfo.get_width(),
    'height': format(vinfo.get_height()),
    'depth': format(vinfo.get_depth()),
    'framerate': 'Frate: {}'.format(vinfo.get_framerate_num()),
    'bitrate': 'Brate: {}'.format(vinfo.get_max_bitrate()),
    'par': vinfo.get_par_num(),
    'fname': vinfo.get_caps().to_string().split(',')[0]
}
```

---

I'd also go on to say that you can change the code to return a dictionary and you can then remove all the `field` stuff from this function.
And you can use a [list comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) to return a dictionary for every `info.get_video_streams()`.

which leads to:

```
def get_file_info(f, stream):
    discoverer = GstPbutils.Discoverer()
    discoverer.connect('discovered', on_discovered)
    info = discoverer.discover_uri(f)
    duration = convert_time(info.get_duration(), 'hh:mm:ss')
    return [
        {
            'duration': duration,
            'type': vinfo.get_stream_type_nick(),
            'width': vinfo.get_width(),
            'height': format(vinfo.get_height()),
            'depth': format(vinfo.get_depth()),
            'framerate': 'Frate: {}'.format(vinfo.get_framerate_num()),
            'bitrate': 'Brate: {}'.format(vinfo.get_max_bitrate()),
            'par': vinfo.get_par_num(),
            'fname': vinfo.get_caps().to_string().split(',')[0],
        }
        for vinfo in info.get_video_streams()
    ]

def get_file_field(f, stream, field):
    videos = get_file_info(f, stream)
    video_info = videos[-1]
    if stream == 'video':
        return str(video_info[field])
```

Comment: I'm confused by the get_file_info return code.  You are returning a list that contains a dict (I think commas missing between key:value pairs), and then a for loop?  I've never seen anything like this

Comment: @joelgoldstick Thank you, I forgot to add commas in my dictionary, ): I'm using a list comprehension to return a list. It's like `map` but simpler to write. I can't really find anything that explains it too well, but [these may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list-comprehension%20python?sort=votes&mode=all), and it's a way to remove the `l=[];for a in ...: l.append(a); return l` idiom.

Comment: This is beautiful :)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, the first part of you code looks fine.

However, all the `elif` calls can be avoided. The first `if` is necessary, since you're calling `convert_time`. The others can be simplified, if you know the fields are one of the 9 you are listing. Instead of checking if the names are similar, and then call `str(string)`, you can use the field name directly, in combination with `locals()`.

I believe this is a better way to do it:

```
if stream == 'video':
       if field == 'duration':
           return str(convert_time(info.get_duration(), 'hh:mm:ss'))
       else
           return str(locals()[field])
```

`locals()[field]` will return whatever `field` contains. Then, str(locals()[field])` will convert it to a string.

```
width = 2    
height = 3    
name = 'Name of video'

field = 'width'    
str(locals()[field])
Out[5]: '2'

field = 'name'    
str(locals()[field])
Out[7]: 'Name of video'
```

---

<sub>Note, I'm not the most experienced Python user, so it's possible that there are better ways to do this.</sub>

Comment: A safer alternate to this is to use [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). `eval` is ok, but may lead to bad or unsafe habits.

Comment: Thanks @JoeWallis =) I didn't know it could be used here. I'm quite sure both me, OP and others would be happy to see a review that explains how to solve this in a better, safer way =) I'll look into how `dict` can be used here when I have the time =)

Comment: @StewieGriffin just replace `eval(field)` with `locals()[field]`

Comment: @StewieGriffin or use a pre-meditated explicit dict for this purpose in the for-loop: `d = {'ftype': (vinfo.get_stream_type_nick()), 'width': vinfo.get_width(), ...}` and then you can use `d[field]` instead of `eval(field)`

Comment: @JoeWallis @StewieGriffin: `ast.literal_eval(...)` is a possible replacement for `eval(...)` as well.

Comment: But using `locals` you could query fields not intended for that use, like `discoverer`. Using a dictionary, like Joe suggested is much better idea.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, this was a mere suggestion, and I guess OP has discovered that Joe's answer is superior. I'll go through his answer later, and learn some stuff myself =)